# how to use custom created font in google sheet

Tags: google-sheets, fonts, webfonts, google-webfonts

in google sheet when using Delius unicase font, cell A10 displays h as H because Delius unicase font has the same glyph for h & H. so ve use custom created Delius unicase font in which h & H having different looking glyph.

[image: google sheet with Delius unicase font in google chrome with Delius unicase 2 font]

so kindly inform if there is a way for using a custom-created font in google sheet.

delius unicase font: https://github.com/Font77/7f/blob/master/cpp_phont24/delius26_2.ttf

Comment: fortunately most likely not doable